# Given the pairwise edit distance of a and b and b and c, can we find the pairwise edit distance of a and c?

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming, edit-distance

If we have three string a, b, c and we know ( or already calculated ) edit_distance(a,b) and edit_distance(b,c), can we efficiently calculate edit_distance(a,c) without actually comparing a and c.

*edit_distance(a,b) = number of character insertion, deletion and replacement required to convert a into b.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, no.  For example, take

- a = CAP
- b = CAT
- c = CAR

Here, edit_distance(a, b) = 1 and edit_distance(b, c) = 1.  Moreover, edit_distance(a, c) = 1.

However, we could also have

- a = CAP
- b = CAT
- c = RAT

Here, edit_distance(a, b) = 1 and edit_distance(b, c) = 1, but edit_distance(a, c) = 2.  Therefore, there is no way to purely use the edit distances of a and b and of b and c to compute the edit distance of a and c.

However, we *do* know that edit_distance(a, c) ≤ edit_distance(a, b) + edit_distance(b, c), since you can always apply the transformations in sequence to turn a into c.  More generally, edit distance forms a discrete [distance metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29), which forms the basis of the [BK-tree data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BK-tree).

Hope this helps!

Comment: We also know that `edit_distance(a, c) &ge; abs(edit_distance(a, b) - edit_distance(b, c))`; in other words, each insertion/deletion/replacement in one transformation might cancel out a single insertion/deletion/replacement in the other, but it can't do more than that.

Comment: @KyleStrand Actually, d(a,c) >= |d(a,b)-d(b,c)| is implied from the triangle inequality with some algebra.

d(a,b) <= d(a,c) + d(b,c) implies d(a,c) >= d(a,b) - d(b,c);
and
d(b,c) <= d(a,c) + d(a,b) implies d(a,c) >= d(b,c) - d(a,b).

The two above statements imply d(a,c) >= |d(a,b) - d(b,c)|.

Comment: Another good example is the case of `a = CAT, b = CAP, c = CAT`. There's no way to determine from the distance metric alone that `d(a,c) == 0`